# Setting the value of a C-SET from a BEAN-WRITE

Tags: java, jsp, dynamic, javabeans, jsp-tags

I'm banging my head up against the wall on this one.  Google hasn't been able to give a straight answer, or maybe I'm just reading it wrong.  Here's what I'm trying to do...

I have a series of buttons that need to link to a variety of places depending on some IDs, these ID are retrieved by writing a couple of beans to the links. what I would like to do is somehow dynamically write out all of the links, stick them in a forEach loop and have the links write themselves depending on the beans that are written.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<c:set var="alphaID"><bean:write name="linka" property="alphaID" bundle="navigation" filter="true"/></c:set>
<c:set var="betaID"><bean:write name="linkb" property="betaId" bundle="navigation" filter="true"/></c:set>
<c:set var="buttonURL" value="detail.jsp?alphaID=${alphaID}&betaID=${betaID}"/></c:set>
<a href="${buttonURL}">Button</a>
```

I just can't seem to get this right.  I know I'm close, I just can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="alphaID" value="${navigation.alphaID}"/>
<c:set var="betaID"value="${navigation.betaId}"/>
<c:set var="buttonURL" value="detail.jsp?alphaID=${alphaID}&betaID=${betaID}"/></c:set>
<a href="${buttonURL}">Button</a>
```

Something like this should get you going.

Comment: Does it matter that the NAMES of the bean:writes are different?